# Xamarin crashes editing shader code

Tags: macos, opengl, xamarin, glsl, xamarin-studio

Writing `if` statements in my GLSL shader code crashes Xamarin Studio. Also declaring a `vec3`, `vec4` or other miscellaneous data types will initiate the eternal hang also.

It seems Xamarin can't parse the foreign language. And that's fine, I don't need it to, but I do need to be able to work on my code.

Can I disable parsing, error checking, etc for specific files in my solution?

Comment: Which version of `Xamarin Studio` are you running on OS-X?

Comment: Running 5.10.2 (Build 56), it happened in the previous build too.

Comment: Personally I would at least try the alpha version `Version 6.1 (build 817)` if that is possible in your environment. The entire intellisense was redone using the Rosyln compiler as a service, that along with a ton of other changes/enhancements/bug fixes makes it worthwhile for me (not that is bug-free, remember it is a prerelease version)

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot. It's stable?

Comment: Stable? For the most part, yes, I'm using it for production code... I have noticed a few glitches here and there and have had the occasion hang and/or crash. Again, its a pre-release preview so if you do experience issues/bugs I would recommend reporting them via bugzilla.xamarin.com ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(extending our comments from your question)

**Xamarin 6.1** editing shader files with if/else, vec2/vec3/vec4, etc..  without any issues:

[image]

Shown is a Addin that extends the mime type `text/x-cgsrc` ([CGSyntaxMode.xml](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/2945ef1e5db5acca77b48f10c9ce982273480c3b/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor/SyntaxModes/CGSyntaxMode.xml)) with some minor additions for:

```
<File pattern="*.shader" />
<File pattern="*.fs" />  
<File pattern="*.vs" />  
<File pattern="*.cginc" />  
<File pattern="*.vert" />  
<File pattern="*.tese" />  
<File pattern="*.tesc" />  
<File pattern="*.geom" />  
<File pattern="*.frag" />  
<File pattern="*.comp" />
```

Dark Theme setting in 6.1:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that dark theme. Upgrading now.

Comment: @livin_amuk Yep, all they had to do was match Visual Studio's theme and they got acquired, hahaahhahahaha

Comment: How do I convert `CGSyntaxMode.xml` to a recognised add-in?

Comment: @livin_amuk Xamarin only applies that mime type to `.cg` files, I uploaded a Xamain Studio 6.0 version @ https://github.com/sushihangover/SushiHangover.Shader.Syntax/releases/tag/v1.0.0 If you have any issues or changes, just post an issue @ https://github.com/sushihangover/SushiHangover.Shader.Syntax/issues